# Most complex WMS mapserver?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, gis, mapserver, wms

i'm building a client-side WMS parser (flex/ActionScript 3) & i'd like to test against as complex a WMS mapserver as i can find. can anyone point me to some sites?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.skylab-mobilesystems.com/en/wms_serverlist.html
http://onearth.jpl.nasa.gov/

You can also easily setup your own to test non tested features you might have with the above:

http://mapserver.osgeo.org/ogc/wms_server.html